# JSONDecodeError with Scrapy: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: scrapy, python-requests, scrapyd

I am using requests in order to fetch and parse some data scraped using Scrapy **with** Scrapyrt (real time scraping).

This is how I do it:

```
#pass spider to requests parameters # 
params = {
        'spider_name': spider,
        'start_requests':True
        }
# scrape items
response = requests.get('http://scrapyrt:9080/crawl.json', params)
print ('RESPONSE JSON',response.json())
data = response.json()
```

As per Scrapy [documentation](https://scrapyrt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#id1), with `'start_requests'` parameter set as `True`, the spider automatically requests urls and passes the response to the parse method which is the default method used for parsing requests.

> start_requests
>
> type: boolean
>
> optional
>
> Whether spider should execute Scrapy.Spider.start_requests method. start_requests are executed by default when you run Scrapy Spider normally without ScrapyRT, but this method is NOT executed in API by default. By default we assume that spider is expected to crawl ONLY url provided in parameters without making any requests to start_urls defined in Spider class. start_requests argument overrides this behavior. **If this argument is present API will execute start_requests Spider method**.

But the setup is not working. Log:

```
[2019-05-19 06:11:14,835: DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-4] Starting new HTTP connection (1): scrapyrt:9080
[2019-05-19 06:11:15,414: DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-4] http://scrapyrt:9080 "GET /crawl.json?spider_name=precious_tracks&start_requests=True HTTP/1.1" 500 7784
[2019-05-19 06:11:15,472: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task project.api.routes.background.scrape_allmusic[87dbd825-dc1c-4789-8ee0-4151e5821798] raised unexpected: JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/project/api/routes/background.py", line 908, in scrape_allmusic
    print ('RESPONSE JSON',response.json())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: You'll have to provide more details about how you've installed Twisted 18, since everyone else [in that issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/311) reports that fixing Twisted fixes their problem

Comment: I've edited the question. Actually, my question has opened another issue, because is related to scrapytr and not scrapyd. Please refer to edit.

Comment: Have you checked what the contents of the response are? (`response.text`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to a bug with Twisted `19.2.0`, a scrapyrt dependency, which assumed response to be of wrong type.

Once I installed `Twisted==18.9.0`, it worked.

Comment: It is recommended here that self-answers are accepted, to mark the question as answered. To accept a question, click on the tick mark adjacent to the answer. Thanks!